# How to stop PHP Domdocument::SaveXML from inserting "CDATA"?

Tags: php, javascript, dom, cdata

I'm using PHP to get all the "script" tags from web pages, and then appending text after the </script> that is not always valid html. Because it's not always valid markup I can't just use appendchild/replacechild to add that information, unless I'm misunderstanding how replacechild works.

Anyway, when I do

```
$script_tags = $doc->getElementsByTagName('script');
$l = $script_tags->length;
for ($i = $l - 1; $i > -1; $i--)
$script_tags_string = $doc->saveXML($script_tags->item($i));
```

This puts "<![CDATA[" and "]]>" around the contents of the script tag. How can I disable this? Please don't tell me to just delete it afterwards, that's what I'm going to do if I can't find a solution for this.

Comment: CDATA is required, as JS can/will contain `<` and `>`, which the XML parser will see as invalid tags.

Comment: So since I'm exporting for XML purposes I'm not supposed to be able to disable it? Argh. Makes sense though.

Comment: Yep. Unless you can absolutely guarantee that the JS code won't ever use any of the XML metacharacters (`<>&"'`), cdata has to be there.

Comment: Well... strictly speaking CDATA is not necessarily needed. If the result will be handled with XML tools, you could omit the CDATA directive and escape the reserved XML characters to entities instead. In the real world nobody ever wants this because escaping makes the code hideous. So your choices are 1) use CDATA 2) make javascript look ugly 3) output garbage (because not using CDATA or entities will probably result in something that is not XML).

Answer (score 3):

I have a suspicion that the CDATA is inserted because it would otherwise be invalid XML.

Have you tried using `saveHTML` instead of `saveXML`?

Comment: I usually use saveHTML but I switched to saveXML because HTML stopped working in this case. Actually, I was using a function I copied and pasted from someone's blog that used saveHTML, so I'll try playing with it and see if I can get it working.

Answer (score 0):

One way I've found to fix this:

Before echoing the document, make a loop around all script tags, and use str_replace for "<", ">" to some string, make sure to only use that string inside script tags.
Then, use the method saveXML() in a variable, and finally use str_replace replacing "STRING" to "<" or ">"

Here is the code:

```
<?php
    //First loop
    foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('script') as $script){
        $script->nodeValue = str_replace("<", "ESCAPE_CHAR_LT", $script->nodeValue);
        $script->nodeValue = str_replace(">", "ESCAPE_CHAR_GT", $script->nodeValue);
    }

    //Obtaining XHTML
    $output = $dom->saveXML();

    //Seccond replace
    $output = str_replace("ESCAPE_CHAR_LT", "<", $output);
    $output = str_replace("ESCAPE_CHAR_GT", ">", $output);

    //Print document
    echo $output;
?>
```

As you can see, now you are free to use "<" ">" in your scripts.

Hope this helps someone.